# how to change a dataframe column to a string

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

firs3 is a data frame that had work done to it, and now I want to return the STNAME column as a list of strings containing the STNAMES only, how can I do that?

```
print(first3.loc['STNAME'])
```

Comment: `first3.STNAME.astype(str).values`?

Comment: `first3['STNAME'].tolist()`? or with loc you need to add `:` for all rows: `first3.loc[:,'STNAME'].tolist()`